# Take screenshot of youtube video playing in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I am embedding youtube on my web app and I want to take a screenshot of specific timestamp programmatically by js.
So that I can store images of in the DB.

I tried html2canvas but it is not working out, please help.